# Datastax 5.0 and json.facet

Tags: solr, datastax

We have a cluster of SolrCloud 6.0 and using json.facet parameters and want to use Datastax 5.0 and its Solr version is 4.10. Does this version of Datastax supports querying solr using the json.facet parameter?

Answer (score 1):

DSE 5.1 does support this. It's supported through the traditional HTTP API as well as through a custom CQL extended API that provides more performance among other benefits (cluster awareness).

Comment: Thanks, but is this version available now?